# How to have two navbars on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two navbars on one page. One is a navbar over the image and the other a dropdown navbar. When resizing the page, I want the navbar over image to disappear and the dropdown to appear. However, it ends up with navbar over image sitting on-top of dropdown navbar. Don't know how to change.

I have created the following snippet to showcase my problem:

```js
/* dropdown_navbar start */
// When the user scrolls down 134px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 134 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 134) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
/* dropdown_navbar end */




function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar-right") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar-right";
  }
}
```

```css
/*DROPDOWN NAV */
#myTopnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/*  .navbar-right { 
      float: right
    } */

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active { /* fix as this is not working */
  background-color: rgb(40, 129, 202);
  color: #ddd;
}


/* RESPONSIVE FOR NAVBAR START */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  #navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  #navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
/*DROPDOWN NAV */


/*NAVBAR OVER IMAGE*/

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .topnav a.active {
    background-color: rgb(40, 129, 202);
    color: white;
  } 
  
  .bg-img {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../images/numbers-01.jpg");
    /*min-height: 380px;*/
    min-height: 480px;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    /* Needed to position the navbar */
    position: relative;
  }
  
  /* Position the navbar container inside the image */
  .nav-container-image {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 90px;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  /* The navbar */
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden; /* delete to remove background */
    background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
  }
  
  /* Navbar links */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
 

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav-container-image { 
      width: 200px; /* change width on navbar over image */
    }
  }
/*NAVBAr OVER IMAGE*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown_navbar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar_over_image.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bg-img">
      <div class="nav-container-image">
        <div class="topnav">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Homes</a>
          <a href="#services">Services</a>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="navbar" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px">
  <!--<a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a> -->
        <div class="navbar-right" id="myTopnav">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#services">Services</a>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>

          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    
    <div style="padding:5px 15px 5000px">
      <p><b>This example demonstrates how to slide down a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
      <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
      <p>Scroll to the top to hide the navbar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To preserve your question's long-term value, your code should be in the question itself, not just merely linked-to off-site.  What happens when the code at that link changes or the link itself goes dead?  Your question would become useless for future readers.

Comment: Please insert your code directly in the question.

Comment: Hi Amy, thanks for your comment. However, I tried to add the code but it would not be accepted, hence the link to Codepen

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
function  hideMenu () {

   if (window.width < 768) { 
       document.getElementByClassName("topnav").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```